# Launch Windows program from Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

Is it possible to launch a Windows program from the Cygwin Shell? (similar to firing unix commands in PHP with "exec(…)")

My example: I'd like to launch a database backup in cygwin, however the mysqldump does not exist for cygwin. Therefore I need to fallback to the Windows version (c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump …). Is it possible to launch this from within Cygwin?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just run it. The path is probably something like `/cygdrive/c/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump`. Just remember that any paths you pass TO `mysqldump` need to be in Windows (not cygwin) format. Or you can use the `cygpath` program to convert the paths for you.

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way:

In .bashrc, add `alias start='cmd /c start'`

Then use the start command as needed.

```
start .
```

Open the current directory in Explorer

```
start winword log.txt
```

Open log.txt in Word

There's also "cygstart" that may also work for you.

Comment: `cygstart` is the easiest, at least for launching windows explorer

Comment: @SridharSarnobat In my current situation this comment of yours helped me more than any of the actual answers here.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer from [SO site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952433/how-to-start-a-windows-gui-program-in-cygwin) useful.

Find ".bash_profile" file in your Cygwin installation path ( cygwin\home\user-name )

Put following lines in a file.

```
export desktop="desktop path"

alias chrome="cygstart C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

alias dbDump="c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump"
```

save and close the file.

NOTE: It is important to escape characters in path and path should be in POSIX format, not in windows format.
start bash prompt. Execute

```
$chrome
```

This will open chrome window.
or

```
$dbDump
```

This will execute mysqldump program.

If you want to change present working directory to desktop then

```
$>cd $desktop
```