# Bash/Cygwin - aliases not behaving like command

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin

I'm trying to get Cygwin setup the tools I use in Windows and am having some troubles. From [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/293027/launch-windows-program-from-cygwin), I found I could specify Notepad++ as my editor using

```
alias notepad="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

And this works when I run it through the command line

```
notepad $( cygpath -pw ~/.bashrc ) &
```

opens my .bashrc file, however when I try and make this an alias

```
alias settings="notepad $( cygpath -pw ~/.bashrc ) &"
```

and type `settings` I get the get the error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\cygwin64homeuser.bashrc doesn't exist. Create it?
```

I tried defining a variable and had even more issues. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes in the alias command, so whatever is in the double quotes is executed **at the time you are setting the alias**. You have to use single quotes around the alias definition, so that variables are resolved when the alias is used. For instance, try these two:

```
alias wtf1='echo $(pwd)'
alias wtf2="echo $(pwd)"
```

You will see that `wtf1` properly reports the current directory, while `wtf2` seems stuck on the directory you were in when you set up the alias.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue. I updated the `$PATH` under Cygwin and removed `/usr/local/bin` by mistake. Only later I noticed that git aliases stopped working. Restoring the `PATH` resolved it.